# Java version is not updated even after setting a new path

Tags: java, path, environment-variables

I installed Java version "10.0.2" in 2018, but I'm trying to update it to "11.0.2" (I know that this is still old compared to the current latest version "13.0.2", but I need to set it "11.0.2" for a particular project that I'm working on).

I downloaded the zip file and opened it up under the C drive, and tried to change the path.

[image: Environment variables]

[image: New path added]

A new path was added, so I opened a command prompt and checked the Java version with `Java -version` command, but it is still "10.0.2", even though it does say that the Java execution file is stored in the new path `C:\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe` when I tried `where java` command like this.

[image: Java version]

Any idea on why this is happening? And how can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

I tried the advice I got on the comment section.

[image]

I also tried moving up the newly added path like this.

[image: Moved up]

I tried deleting other other six paths (of course I took a backup), but this didn't work either.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to set it temporarily in your command shell. Can you try this in command prompt?:

    set JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk-11.0.2
    set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

Afterwards try again.

Comment: Looks like the java executable is in your path twice and the first one is executed.

Comment: Make sure, that your desired Java Version is in front of the PATH variable. Otherwise  it could be, that it is present under another location in your path, which is used instead.

Comment: @Quadrivics I tried it on command prompt, but it didn't work. I pasted a screenshot of what I did on the original post, which you can see below "UPDATE".

Comment: @dave There are 6 other paths besides the one ```C:\jdk-11.0.2\bin``` that I added. How can I make ```C:\jdk-11.0.2\bin``` the first one to be executed? I tried "Move up" button to place it at the top of the other 6 paths, but the result didn't change.

Comment: @JanHeld Could you explain what you mean by "the desired Java Version is in front of the PATH variable"? Does it mean moving up ```C:\jdk-11.0.2\bin``` to the top? (See "UPDATE" in my original post for what I mean by "Move up the newly added path")

Comment: I would try to put the path `C:\jdk-11.0.2\bin` in front of your PATH variable, instead of appending it. That should be it.

Comment: Please look at the latest update in my original post. Instead of appending the path like ```C:\Users\marra\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\jdk-11.0.2\bin```, I edited the path like ```C:\jdk-11.0.2\bin```, but still the result is the same.

Comment: Perhaps you could try an install with SDKMan: https://sdkman.io/install
It's a commandline program to help you manage installs like the JRE and it does a lot of stuff for you. As a last resort you could try running something in Eclipse or IntelliJ to see if it picks it up there.

Comment: Thanks! The problem has been solved.